# How can I let the a tag vertical center to the footer tag?

Tags: html, css

How can I let the `<a>` tag vertical center to the `<footer>` tag?

This below is my css:

```
.header-article-list a {

    width:50%;
    color: #000000;
}

.header-article-list .prev-btn {


   float:left;

}
.header-article-list .next-btn {

    float:right;
}
```

It did not let the `<a>` tag vertical center to the `<footer>` tag.

This is the `<footer>` in browser:

[image]

This is the `<a>` tag in browser:

[image]

This is the `<span>` tag:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I set css to below:

```
.header-article-list a {

    overflow:hidden;
    width:50%;
    color: #000000;
}

.header-article-list .prev-btn {


  /** float:left; **/

}
.header-article-list .next-btn {

  /**  float:right;**/
}
```

Get the below effect:

[image]

---

**EDIT-2**

There is `text-align:center` inherit from `header-article-list`, I uncheck it in browser:

[image]

Comment: try `.header-article-list {overflow:hidden}` or use clearfix hacks

Comment: Hey what you actually wana do ?? You have just repeated everywhere "tag"

Comment: @IsmailFarooq  this do not work.

Comment: @Ashishsah The a tag means `<a>`, the footer tag means `<footer>`

Comment: @244boy can i see live ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Oh, it works. But they are next to each other, how to let them separated more?

Comment: please provide screenshot

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Have done that.

Comment: @244boy remove width and check is there any text align property on parent ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq See my edit-2

Comment: Hello, providing a snippet (HTML+CSS) would have been easier and more effective  than screenshots of code and visual ;) . in my humble opinion

Comment: oh add overflow hidden on `.header-article-list` not on anchor tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in  css:

```
footer {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <footer align="center">
    <a href="#">March 25, 2</a>
   </footer>
```

You can show the example here:http://jsfiddle.net/9yNT3/3/

Answer (score 0):

If it's `inline` you can just add `text-align: center;` to the parent `<footer>`.

If it is `display:block`, give it a width and add `margin:auto;` for horizontal centering.